# All pages and posts returning 404 Wordpress (permalink issue)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have changed permalink settings in my Wordpress website and now all pages return 404 error.
I have tried the following (none of them worked for me)

1. Removing .htaccess file and change permalink configuration from Wordpress admin panel so it overrites the file with a correct .htaccess configuration
2. Cheching whether Apache2 server has Allow Override directive (It has the directive enabled)
3. Checking file permissions (they are okey -- -rw-r--r-- )
4. Uninstalling all plugins

[Rest api error 404 while trying to configurate WooCommerce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pes7b.png)

Comment: What 'settings' did you change? If it was code based could you provide the code related to your permalinks?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `flush_rewrite_rules` (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/).

Just put it into your active theme's `functions.php` file (e.g. at the beginning) and refresh your page. Then remove it.

Comment: I did that and doesn't work. Is very strange because .htaccess file rewrites just well. Even if I remove the file and then change permalinks configuration through Wordpress the file is created again with the right configuration but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings » Permalinks, and simply click on the Save Changes button. This will update your permalinks settings and flush rewrite rules. In most cases, this solution fixes the WordPress posts 404 error. However, if it does not work for you, then you probably need to update your .htaccess file manually.

You can also manually add this code in your .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: I already had that on .htaccess file. Don't know what's happening, is very strange.